# Location of Mozilla Core Javascript Modules

Tags: javascript, thunderbird, jsm

Where are the JavaScript core modules listed on [this Mozilla page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules)?

I looked through the docs forever and ran all types of searches for `*.jsm` and a few specific `jsm` files, but I couldn't find any.

Are these separate files located somewhere or are they built into the executable somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went perusing through the source and found the .jsm files. They're in the toolkit and I'm guessing they get compiled into some binary during the make.

https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-beta/source/toolkit/modules